# Google calendar API free slots

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

i am really new to the coding and would like to ask for some advice regarding calendar API.
I managed to created a list of the events and and show a busy time in the calendar, but i cant figure out how to show output of the free slots between the events.

```
# Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='<email>', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        #print(start, event['summary'])"""

    cst = timezone('UTC')

    the_datetime_start = cst.localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 10, 0))
    print(the_datetime_start)
    the_datetime_end = cst.localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 10, 16))
    print(the_datetime_end)
    body = {
        "timeMin": the_datetime_start.isoformat(),
        "timeMax": the_datetime_end.isoformat(),
        "timeZone": 'UK',
        "items": [{"id": '<email>'}]
    }

    eventsResult = service.freebusy().query(body=body).execute()

    print(eventsResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you a code answer with your information, but if you want to show your free slots, you just have to:

- Get all the tasks you have on your planning
- Order it
- Compare the first end date/hour task with the second start date/hour task
- The différence between is your free slot, so you have your free slot
- Do it again for the second task and the third task, and repeat for the other task